# Java SAX Xml parser parsing with html special characters [Fatal Error]

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I am having trouble parsing html pages as xml if that page contains special characters like ®(&reg) or &nbsp. Whenever a html file consist either of the following special characters it prompt that it is an error as show below "[Fatal Error] 279:15 The entity "reg" was referenced, but not declared". Any work around solution (without editing the html file) to ignore these special characters?

Comment: Side note: HTML is not XML, you may be better off finding proper parser (for .Net it would be HtmlAgilityPack, but I don't know what Java world offers). I.e. `<b><span>text</b>more<br></span>` is ok HTML, but not an acceptable XML.

Comment: Jericho is a Java HTML parser.